# Cmake build error for lower version of Cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

simple but not simple question here

My Cmake version is 3.5, and the CMakefile requires only 3.13

When I `cmake .. -DTENSORRT_ROOT=/input/TensorRT-6.0.1.5/`

it turns out

```
cmake: /usr/local/miniconda3/envs/dl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
cmake: /usr/local/miniconda3/envs/dl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
cmake: /usr/local/miniconda3/envs/dl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
cmake: /usr/local/miniconda3/envs/dl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.13 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.5.1
```

It's really strange here...

Comment: 13 is greater than 5. Version numbers don't work like decimal numbers.

Comment: Yes, CMake 3.13 is a *higher*, more recent version than 3.5. You need to upgrade your CMake to **at least** 3.13. Download the latest (3.16) [here](https://cmake.org/download/)

Comment: Thanks guys ! I will try it, the numbers are confused...